# Gnome 3 always show ALT+x keyboard shortcuts

Tags: gnome, shortcut, underline

I found out that `"gtk-auto-mnemonic = 0"` is supposed to turn the underlined keyboard shortcuts back on but neither `"gtk-auto-mnemonic = 0"` nor `"gtk-auto-mnemonic = 1"` at the end of every theme file made any difference.

Is this advice only valid for Gnome 2?

**How can I make the shortcuts always visible, not just when I press ALT?**

I did it with

```
locate gtkrc | grep themes | xargs -I @ echo "echo \"gtk-auto-mnemonics = 0\" >> @" | sudo sh
```

And verified with (both with zero and one, as I tried both):

```
~$ locate gtkrc | grep themes | xargs grep auto
/usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/Default/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/Small/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Clearlooks/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Crux/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Default/gtk-2.0-key/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Emacs/gtk-2.0-key/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/HighContrast/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/HighContrastInverse/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Industrial/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/LowContrast/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Mist/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/Redmond/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/ThinIce/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
/usr/share/themes/bubble/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/automatic-mnemonics false
```

According to its schema: *Only show mnemonics on when the Alt key is pressed. Whether mnemonics should be automatically shown and hidden when the user presses the Alt key.*.

Alternatively, you can use *dconf-editor* to change the value.

You will need to re-start the application in order the change makes effect.

Comment: This makes my keybinds *never* show up instead of just when I press alt.

Comment: Did you try it? Did you try to close the application and open it again?

Comment: This works for most of the applications I use, except Vinagre. I took a peek at its source and it seems to have underlines characters where I would expect mnemonics to appear, but they don't...

Comment: [Doesn't work for me](http://askubuntu.com/questions/329668/always-show-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome), I'm afraid. And yes, I did restart the application.

Comment: Which application? The setting depends on the application using dconf.  Older applications might still using gconf.

Comment: In my ubuntu 12.04 I don't have a "dconf" command, but your answer lead me in the right direction and the command that worked for me was:

    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface automatic-mnemonics false